# How to convert int to big-endian 32-bit number in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, websocket

I'm trying to implement WebSocket handshake (76) in ObjC and can't figure out (as I'm new to C and ObjC) how can I get the following:

1. List item
2. I've got two number

   ```
   155712099
   173347027
   ```
3. I need to convert them to 32 bit big-endian numbers
4. concatenate them into a string
5. and express the resulting string in ASCII

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried CFSwapInt32HostToBig. I just don't get how I can see in NSLog a 32 bit number in binary. Fx, NSLog(@"%?", number)

Comment: Set a break point, then right click the variable in your the Variables View and then View Memory of "VariableName"

Comment: There's no `printf()`-style specifier for displaying a number in binary. You'll have to roll your own if you need that functionality.

Comment: @Joe, thanks, good idea.
@Jonathan any hints on how I could do that? a link or smth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using the iPhone SDK, you have access to Core Foundation. Use:

```
uint32_t myInt32Value = ...;
uint32_t myInt32AsABigEndianNumber = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(myInt32Value);
```

Comment: Interesting. The [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/ByteOrdering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001150-CJBEJBHH) says those functions are only available on Mac OS X, but [the function documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001449-CH201-BAJBDHJG) says they're available since iOS 2.0.

Comment: So which one is better in this case CFSwapInt32HostToBig or htonl?

Comment: They do the same mathematical thing. I prefer `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` however because it's inlined (while `htonl()` is `extern`) and because the name better describes what I am trying to accomplish (i.e. swap to big endian, not to network order--unless I'm trying to do something network related, in which case I'd use `htonl()`.)

Comment: @Anomie: Actually, the documentation does not appear to restrict these functions to Mac OS X only. In any event, they've been available on iOS since day one and are fully documented there.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: See the very bottom of the linked page: "Note that Core Foundation’s byte swapping functions are available on Mac OS X only."

Comment: The documentation is mistaken, then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is based on C and usually has the C standard library available, so you can use the standard `htonl` function. You can then do the string manipulation using the normal string functions.